# Как удалить сообщение? pyTelegramBotAPI Python

Tags: python, telebot

Есть бот, написанный на python3 с использованием библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI (telebot)

Надо удалить отправленный ранее документ (гифка).

```
loading_id = bot.send_document(message.chat.id, loading)
...
<удаление сообщения>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py` появились новые методы, в частности:

```
    def delete_message(self, chat_id, message_id):
        """
        Use this method to delete message. Returns True on success. 
        :param chat_id: in which chat to delete
        :param message_id: which message to delete
        :return: API reply.
        """
        return apihelper.delete_message(self.token, chat_id, message_id)
```

Самому нужно было, поэтому наткнулся на твой вопрос, уже попробовал использовать, работает.

Comment: А можно ли как-то удалить все свои сообщения в заданной группе, за много лет сразу?) Как это сделать с помощью PyTelegramBotApi?

Answer (score 1):

```py
loading_id = bot.send_document(message.chat.id, loading)
bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, loading_id.message.id)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В этой библиотеки сообщения об удаление нет согласно (`dir(telebot.TeleBot)`).
Удалить можете с помощью API телеграмма:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/deletemessage?message_id={1}&chat_id={2}'.format(token, message.message_id, message.chat.id))
```

Comment: deleteMessage добавлен [16 Мая](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/pull/325)