# Telebot удаление сообщений в чате

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Всем привет, в телеграмме есть возможность удалить все сообщения от этого пользователя, есть ли какой то метод что бы сделать это ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить сообщение? pyTelegramBotAPI Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665812/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-pytelegrambotapi-python)

Comment: интересует возможность удаления сообщений не по message_id а по user.id

Comment: можно пройтись по всем сообщениям от пользователя по списку и удалять поочерёдно

Comment: здесь есть ньюанс ) пользователь этот бот и по сообщениям его пройтись не представляется возможности

Comment: короче говоря ситуация такая бот добавляется в группу мой бот его блокирует но тот успевает отправить сообщение

Comment: можно хранить в памяти все id's сообщений от пользователей, к примеру, за последний час, чтобы по ним можно было почистить. Хотя, если вы говорите, что "тот успевает отправить СООБЩЕНИЕ", то бишь одно, то можно просто хранить последнее сообщение для каждого пользователя.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том что сообщение ботов другой бот не видит следовательно id этих сообщений я не могу словить, вообще странно что телеграмм не даёт такой возможности