# Как удалить сообщение через минуту?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

У меня есть скрипт на python(telebot), где бот приветствует новых участников группы, надо сделать, что бы это сообщение удалилось через минуту.

Answer (score 1):

Подобный вопрос уже задавался: [Как удалить сообщение? pyTelegramBotAPI Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665812)

Для удаления сообщения есть встроенный метод: `delete_message()`

А чтобы сообщение удалилось через минуту можно написать функцию удаления через 60 сек.
Для этого необходимо написать отдельную функцию ожидания и удаления, например:

```py
import time
def delete_start_message(chat_id, message_id, timer):
    time.sleep(60)
    bot.delete_message(chat_id, message_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись тем, что указывать в коде время:

```
import time

# Функция для удаления сообщения через заданное время
def delete_message(chat_id, message_id, delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    bot.delete_message(chat_id, message_id)

# Обработчик новых участников группы
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def greet_new_members(message):
    # Отправляем сообщение приветствия и сохраняем его идентификатор
    greeting_message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать!")
    greeting_message_id = greeting_message.message_id
    # Запускаем функцию удаления сообщения через 1 минуту (60 секунд)
    delete_message(message.chat.id, greeting_message_id, 60)
```

Если покумекать, можно и вывести в настройках время, но опять таки - лишь пища для размышлений)